# how to get Int type from Either class in scala?

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in scala.  I am playing aroung with it. 
how to get Int type from the variable i in the below peice of codebase.

```
case class Return[A](a: Either[Throwable, A])
val e: Either[Throwable, Int] = Right(12)
val i:Return[Int] = Return(e)
```

Basically, I want something like below.

val a:Int = i

Comment: And what do you want to happen if `e` is a `Left`?

Comment: ignore or throw an error. I just want to retrieve Int part and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward way is do a `get` on the `Right` projection.

```
val r1: Int = i.a.right.get
```

But that's not safe because it will throw a runtime exception if the `Either` is `Left`.

You could test for safety and provide a default value.

```
val r2: Int = if (i.a.isRight) i.a.right.get else -1
```

But the more idiomatic approach is to `fold` over the `Either`.

```
val r3: Int = i.a.fold(l => -1, identity)
```

Of course if you want to re-throw the exception instead of supplying a default value, you could do that instead.

```
val r4: Int = i.a.fold(l => throw l, identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using match case

```
val intData: Int = i match {
   case Right(data) => data
   case Left(ex) => throw new Exception()
}
```

In your case if you just want to throw the exception in Left case the output will be Int always.